# Is there a reason why badges related with bounties are trackable in meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, badge-progress

I can see that the badges [Altruist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist),[Benefactor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/47/benefactor),[Investor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor) and [Promoter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/46/promoter) are trackable in meta:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

They cannot be earned in meta as there aren't any bounties in meta. I think that these badges should not be trackable as they cannot be earned in meta.

Comment: Presumably it's just not worth the bother to remove them.  It's not like it harms anyone for someone to track them.

Comment: @Servy: As long as they are never recommended for tracking, yes, the "damage" is reasonably contained... but that happened with [informed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253486#comment827984_253486).

Comment: Jon Skeet now will try hacking the site for those badges. Anyway, I think it's not worthwhile, but not bad enough not to list it for the future dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an oversight.

Bounty related badges are now excluded from tracking on child-meta sites.

With you in the next build.